# Reloading a specific page in hostinger hosting gives 404 error, its a react website

Tags: reactjs, web, deployment

i have created a react website but problem is when i go to specific  page like contact or about page and refresh the browser or directly open a page like [www.mywebsitedomain.com/about](http://www.mywebsitedomain.com/about) it gives 404 error however on when i run using npm run start in development this thing doesnt happens when i deployed on netlify i used netlify.toml, website runs perfectly first freelance  website i bought hosting and domain on hostinger website crashes

i tried searching but no help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:
[image]

Steps:

1. In your public folder create a file called `.htaccess`
2. Copy and paste the following code in that file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
      RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    </IfModule>
```

3. Build your app using npm run build in terminal.
4. Upload the files inside dist folder into public_html folder of hostinger.
5. Enjoy your routing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally im using Hostinger file manager and I just added the .htaccess with the following code in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```